# arrays in foreach in yii 1

Tags: php, yii, yii1.x

I have following code in my controller:

```
 $data= Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
                    ->select('region_id')
                    ->from('user_rights')
                    ->where('user_group_id='.$findRegion['user_group_id'])
                    ->queryAll();

 foreach($data as $key=>$value){
            $array_o[$key] = $value;
        }
```

`var_dump($array_o);` returns following value:

```
array(2) { [0]=> array(1) { ["region_id"]=> string(4) "1703" } [1]=> array(1) { ["region_id"]=> string(4) "1706" } }
```

But, I need to get similar to following value:

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(4) "1703" [1]=> string(4) "1706" }.
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just set the proper value right from the beginning:

```
foreach ($data as $key => $value){
    $array_o[$key] = $value['region_id'];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [queryColumn()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCommand#queryColumn-detail) method

So it is just enough set statment

```
$data= Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
                ->select('region_id')
                ->from('user_rights')
                ->where('user_group_id='.$findRegion['user_group_id'])
                ->queryColumn();
```

and delete your foreach statment.

Answer (score 1):

Try to make it like this

```
 foreach($data as $key=>$value){
        $array_o[$key] = $value['region_id'];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `foreach` do this:

```
 $array_o[$key] = $value['region_id'];
```